# Issue returning the sum or total of a database search

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need help returning the total of all of the results, the results are a number. I have tried all sorts of queries by searching on here and google but no luck so far.

The query I have is

```
$totalClientAdmin = $db->get_results(
"SELECT total_cost from acp_proformas 
 where debt_id like '{$debtData->id}' 
 and status like 'transferred_to_invoice' ");
```

Now on some cases there is more than 1 invoice so this query brings up all the invoices under a certain debt_id.

I have a table field that should show the total and this is the field.

```
<td class=\"left\" width=\"25%\" >".makeCurrency($totalClientAdmin)."</td>
```

Ive tried arrays, and all sorts to get this working but im stuck so id appreciate an help

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, they all generally say there same but the one ive marked as answer accepted was the one I got to work. To start with I had it returning "Array" then I realised that get_results was wrong, changed it to get_row and then changed my table field to {$totalClientAdmin->total_cost} and boom, works a treat. Thank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

$totalClientAdmin = $db->get_results("SELECT **SUM(total_cost) as total_cost** from acp_proformas where debt_id like '{$debtData->id}' and status like 'transferred_to_invoice' ");

assuming the 'LIKE' statement is correct without '%'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(total_cost) from acp_proformas where debt_id like '{$debtData->id}' and status like 'transferred_to_invoice'
```

That query should just return one number, no matter how many rows there are in the database.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help

```
    SELECT SUM(total_cost) from acp_proformas 
 where debt_id like '{$debtData->id}' 
 and status like 'transferred_to_invoice'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation funcion sum:

```
SELECT sum(total_cost) from acp_proformas
where debt_id like '{$debtData->id}' 
and status like 'transferred_to_invoice'
```

It will return you the sum of the field total_cost over all the result rows. You can also use this function with a group by, to get the sum of the rows that match some grouping criteria.
You can get more information in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum